# Groupoid interpretation of type theory

Tags: lo.logic, ct.category-theory, computer-science

Hello,

I read the paper on groupoid interpretation of type theory by Hofmann and Streicher and I have a question. According to the authors $Tm([[\text{Set}\:[\Gamma]\: ]])$ is the same as $\text{Se}([[\Gamma]])$ but I don't understand because an element of  $Tm([[\text{Set}\,[\Gamma]\:]])$ is a pseudo-fonctor (from $[[\Gamma]]$ to GPD) as said page 10 while an element of $\text{Se}([[\Gamma]])$ is a true fonctor (from $[[\Gamma]]$ to Gpd). Have you an idea ?

Best

P.S: I precise that the paper I mention is entitled *The Groupoid Interpretation of Type Theory* by Martin Hofmann and Thomas Streicher. You can find this article here http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~streicher/
Thanks

Comment: Asymptotik, you'll be more likely to get an answer if you give more details.  Which paper of Hofmann and Streicher is this?  Give a link if you can.  Defining the notation would also increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Does "groupoid" really need a diaeresis over the "i"?

Comment: @Sridhar: I sort of wondered the same thing, but the poster lives in France, where this might be a more customary spelling. (My personal opinion is that diareses are never really needed in English, unless you are under contract with The New Yorker.) 